# O que é a NullPointerException e quais são suas principais causas?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

- O que são exceções `NullPointerException`?
- Quais são suas principais causas?
- Que métodos/práticas podem ser utilizadas para se prevenir?

Comment: Uma das principais causas é quando voce tenta acessar uma posicao que nao existe no vetor/array. Tipo o vetor ter 5 posicoes e voce tentar acessar a sexta posicao.. Ou seja , ela nao existe!

Comment: http://www.devmedia.com.br/java-lang-nullpointerexception-dica/28677

Comment: Isso que você falou de posição fora do intervalo é `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Já acessar uma posição dentro do intervalo porém de array não-inicializado daria `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

O `NullPointerException` é lançado quando se tenta utilizar o `null` tal como se fosse um objeto. Ou seja, é quando você tenta manipular as propriedades, campos, atributos ou métodos de um objeto, mas sem ter esse objeto.

Em muitas outras linguagens de programação também existe o mesmo conceito. Por exemplo, no C# há o `NullReferenceException`. No JavaScript, tentar manipular um `null` incorretamente produz um `TypeError`. Da mesma forma, manipular `None` incorretamente no Python, produz um `AttributeError`.

O restante desta resposta se aplica ao Java, tal como referenciado na pergunta. Mas nas demais linguagens de programação, o que ocorre normalmente é bem parecido com o que é detalhado abaixo.

---

No caso específico do Java, o `NullPointerException` é lançado nas seguintes situações:

1. Tentar acessar um campo de uma instância cuja referência seja `null`.

   ```
   Pessoa p = null;
   String nome = p.nome; // <-- NullPointerException aqui.
   ```
2. Tentar acessar um método de uma instância cuja referência seja `null`.

   ```
   Pessoa p = null;
   String nome = p.getNome(); // <-- NullPointerException aqui.
   ```
3. Tentar usar *autounboxing* de `null`. Este daqui em especial tende a ser uma pegadinha para iniciantes em Java.

   ```
   Integer x = null;
   int z = x; // <-- NullPointerException aqui.
   ```

   Outro exemplo:

   ```
   Integer x = null;
   int z = x + 5; // <-- NullPointerException aqui.
   ```
4. Lançar o `NullPointerException` diretamente (óbvio).

   ```
   throw new NullPointerException();
   ```
5. Tentar lançar `null` como exceção.

   ```
   Exception x = null;
   throw x; // <-- NullPointerException aqui.
   ```
6. Tentar acessar o tamanho de uma variável *array* que tenha o valor `null`.

   ```
   String[] x = null;
   int tamanho = x.length; // <-- NullPointerException aqui.
   ```
7. Tentar acessar um elemento de uma variável *array* que tenha o valor `null`.

   ```
   String[] x = null;
   String y = x[5]; // <-- NullPointerException aqui.
   ```
8. Tentar iterar `null` usando a sintaxe do *for-each*.

   ```
   String[] x = null;
   for (String y : x) { // <-- NullPointerException aqui.
       // ...
   }
   ```
9. Tentar sincronizar (com o bloco `synchronized`) em `null`.

   ```
   Object x = null;
   synchronized (x) { // <-- NullPointerException aqui.
       // ...
   }
   ```
10. Tentar obter uma referência a método a partir de `null`:

    ```
    Pessoa p = null;
    Supplier<String> f = p::toString; // <-- NullPointerException aqui.
    ```

---

As seguintes situações **NÃO** causam `NullPointerException`, ao menos não diretamente:

1. Atribuir `null` à variáveis de tipo objeto.

   ```
   String x = null;
   ```
2. Atribuir `null` à variáveis de tipos primitivos. Isso não compila, logo não vai dar `NullPointerException` :)

   ```
   int x = null; // Erro de compilação!
   ```
3. Passar `null` como parâmetro de métodos ou construtores.

   ```
   System.out.println(null); // Ok.
   String mensagem = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null); // Ok.
   JPanel panel = new JPanel(null); // Ok.
   ```
4. Retornar `null` ou obter `null` como retorno de algum método.

   ```
   public String getXpto() {
       return null;
   }

   public void algumMetodo() {
       String xpto = getXpto(); // Ok. Recebe null.
   }
   ```
5. Colocar o valor `null` em um *array* ou ler o valor `null` de um *array*.

   ```
   String[] array = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
   array[1] = null;
   String valor = array[1]; // Ok. Recebe null.
   ```
6. Passar `null` como um parâmetro *varargs*.

   ```
   private void metodo(String... parametros) {
       System.out.println(parametros);
   }

   private void outroMetodo() {
       // Não dá NullPointerException.
       // Passa como parâmetro um array com um único elemento que é null.
       metodo(null);

       // Não dá NullPointerException.
       // Passa como parâmetro um array com dois elementos null.
       metodo(null, null);

       // Não dá NullPointerException.
       // Passa como parâmetro null.
       metodo((String[]) null);
   }
   ```
7. Iterar um *array* ou `Collection` com elementos `null`.

   ```
   String[] x = new String[] {"a", "b", null, "c"};
   for (String z : x) {
       System.out.println(z);
   }
   ```

   Entretanto, apesar disso ser válido e até útil em algumas vezes, é importante se ter em mente que esta situação ainda é bem convidativa a eventuais `NullPointerException`s, vez que normalmente não é esperado que a variável do laço possa ser `null`:

   ```
   String[] x = new String[] {"a", "b", null, "c"};
   for (String z : x) {
       System.out.println(z.length()); // <-- NullPointerException aqui.
   }
   ```
8. Acessar um campo ou método estático a partir de uma referência `null`. Isso daqui é uma pegadinha da linguagem Java, pois neste caso a única coisa que importa é o tipo da variável, e não o valor.

   ```
   Integer t = null;
   t.parseInt("123"); // Pegadinha: t é null, mas isso NÃO DÁ NullPointerException!
   System s = null;
   Object x = s.out; // Não dá NullPointerException!
   ```

   É importante ressaltar também que usar uma variável para acessar um método estático é uma má prática de programação, pois deixa o código confuso ao utilizar uma variável de forma desnecessária. Não faça isso.
9. Tentar utilizar uma variável local não-inicializada ou potencialmente não-inicializada. Isso daqui dá erro de compilação, logo não dá `NullPointerException`.

   ```
   Pessoa p;
   p.setNome("Maria"); // Erro de compilação, a variável p não foi inicializada.

   Pessoa q;
   if (x > y) q = new Pessoa(); // Pode inicializar ou não, dependendo da condição do if.

   // Erro de compilação, a variável q possivelmente não foi inicializada.
   q.setNome("Maria");
   ```

   Vale ressaltar que esta regra só vale para variáveis locais dentro dos métodos e construtores. Ela **NÃO** se aplica a campos de objetos e variáveis estáticas.
10. Lembre-se que a referência `this` nunca será `null`. Portanto um `NullPointerException` nunca será causado devido a tentativa de manipular-se campos e invocar métodos no objeto `this`.
11. Um construtor nunca retorna `null`. Portanto, sempre que for atribuído a uma variável o resultado da chamada de um construtor, garantidamente o que será atribuído será algo que não é `null`. Logo, tomando como exemplo o código abaixo, é impossível que a variável `p` receba `null`, independente do que estiver ocorrendo dentro do construtor.

    ```
    Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
    ```
12. O operador `instanceof` sempre resulta em `false` quando testado com `null`, e nunca lança `NullPointerException`. Logo, se ele resultar em `true`, o valor testado é garantidamente não nulo.

    ```
    Animal p = ...;
    if (p instanceof Cachorro) {
        // Se entrar aqui, além de sabermos que p é instância de Cachorro,
        // também sabemos que p não é null.
    }
    ```
13. *Casts* nunca lançam `NullPointerException`s (mas podem lançar `ClassCastException`s). Em especial, o *cast* realizado com o valor `null` sempre será bem sucedido.

    ```
    Animal a = null;

    // Recebe null. Não lança NullPointerException e nem ClassCastException.
    Cachorro c = (Cachorro) a;
    ```
14. Há quem pense que acessar um *array* em um índice inválido causa um `NullPointerException`. **Isso não é verdade.** A exceção lançada neste caso será `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Igualmente, tentar acessar os caracteres de uma `String` em posições inválidas também não causa um `NullPointerException` e neste caso a exceção será `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
15. Tentar concatenar `null` a uma `String`.

    ```
    String x = "a" + null + "b"; // Recebe "anullb". Não dá NullPointerException.
    ```

---

Quase todos os casos onde um `NullPointerException` ocorre se deve a algum erro de programação (e por causa disso, quase nunca faz sentido tentar tratá-lo). Portanto, se você obter um `NullPointerException`, provavelmente você (ou alguma outra pessoa) fez algo errado no código. Por esta razão, para se proteger contra o `NullPointerException`, o principal a se fazer é examinar a lógica do seu programa para certificar-se que você nunca cairá em um caso onde um `NullPointerException` possa ser lançado, tal como mostrado nas situações acima no começo desta resposta (e com os contra-exemplos acima também). A sua principal arma contra esse tipo de erro é o `if`:

```
if (x == null) {
    // Faz alguma coisa. Não utiliza o x aqui.
} else {
    // Pode utilizar o x seguramente.
}
```

Também é válido colocar guardas em métodos (e construtores) para se proteger de referências nulas vindas "de fora", usando o `if`. Isso não vai fazer o erro de programação envolvendo referências `null` desaparecerem, mas vai fazer eles se manifestarem mais próximos de sua origem, tendo então uma identificação mais fácil e portanto sendo mais fáceis de se rastrear e se corrigir. Além disso, desta forma fica mais simples de garantir que o seu método está livre de erros, pois isso elimina uma categoria inteira de possíveis erros de programação que ele poderia ter e de brinde você garante que ele não causará nenhum efeito colateral estranho por ter executado apenas pela metade antes de ser abortado pelo `NullPointerException`. A ideia é que se o `null` estiver sendo usado de forma inadequada (o que é um erro de programação), então o erro de programação não será responsabilidade do seu método, e sim de quem o chamou de forma inadequada. Eis aqui um exemplo simples:

```
public void cadastrarNome(String nome) {
    if (nome == null) throw new NullPointerException("Não pode cadastrar um nome nulo.");
    // ... Resto do método.
}
```

Ou então, você pode usar uma exceção diferente:

```
public void cadastrarNome(String nome) {
    if (nome == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Não pode cadastrar um nome nulo.");
    }
    // ... Resto do método.
}
```

Isso também não se limita apenas à validação de parâmetros:

```
public double somarParcelas() {
    if (parcela1 == null || parcela2 == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Nem todas as parcelas foram adquiridas");
    }
    // ... Resto do método.
}
```

Uma outra forma de se implementar estes guardas é utilizando-se o método [`Objects.requireNonNull()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.lang.String-). Este método lança um `NullPointerException` se receber como parâmetro `null`:

```
public void cadastrarNome(String nome) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(nome, "Não pode cadastrar um nome nulo.");
    // ... Resto do método.
}

public double somarParcelas() {
    Objects.requireNonNull(parcela1, "A primeira parcela ainda não foi adquirida.");
    Objects.requireNonNull(parcela2, "A segunda parcela ainda não foi adquirida.");
    // ... Resto do método.
}
```

Também é válido encapsular as suas referências com a classe [`java.util.Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

```
String x = ...;
Optional<String> opt = Optional.ofNullable(x);
// Neste ponto, opt nunca será nulo, e portanto pode ser
// sempre utilizado seguramente (embora o conteúdo dele possa ser nulo).
```

Assim como se proteger de `null`s vindos de fora com os guardas mostrados acima, também é importante não propagar valores `null`s se você puder evitar isso. Por causa disso, é bom também evitar retornar `null`s nos métodos quando ele for devolver algo que representa "vazio", "não inicializado", "não se aplica", "não existe" ou "não encontrado". Nestes casos, eis o que você poderia fazer:

- Caso o seu método retorne uma `String`, talvez seja melhor retornar `""` (uma `String` vazia) ao invés de `null`.
- Caso o seu método retorne um tipo empacotado de primitivo (`Integer`, `Double`, `Long`, etc.), talvez seja melhor retornar zero ao invés de `null`. E se for o caso de retornar zero, mudar o tipo de retorno para o tipo primitivo, se possível, também seria uma boa ideia.
- Caso o seu método retorne um *array*, talvez seja melhor retornar um *array* de tamanho zero ao invés de `null`.
- Caso o seu método retorne uma `Collection`, talvez seja melhor retornar `Collections.emptyCollection()`, `Collections.emptyList()` ou `Collections.emptySet()` ao invés de `null`.
- Caso o seu método retorne um `Map`, talvez seja melhor retornar `Collections.emptyMap()` ao invés de `null`.
- Caso o seu método retorne um `Stream`, talvez seja melhor retornar `Stream.empty()` ao invés de `null`.
- Caso o seu método retorne um `Optional`, então é uma péssima ideia retornar `null` porque isso vai diretamente contra a ideia do `Optional`. Neste caso seria melhor retornar `Optional.empty()` ao invés de `null`.
- Caso o seu método retorne alguma coisa `XYZ` para a qual não há algo que represente o "vazio", "não inicializado", "não se aplica", "não existe" ou "não encontrado", talvez mudar o tipo de retorno para `Optional<XYZ>` seja uma boa ideia. Ou então você poderia usar o padrão de projeto [***Null Object***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) (que eu explicarei um pouco abaixo).

Na prática, podemos fazer algo assim:

```
public class MeuBean {
    private String nome;
    private List<Pessoa> pessoas;

    // Outros métodos...

    public String getNome() {
        return nome == null ? "" : nome;
    }

    public List<Pessoa> getPessoas() {
        return pessoas == null ? Collections.emptyList() : pessoas;
    }
}
```

E por sinal, voltando aos parâmetros, podemos fazer algo parecido com os guardas. Ao invés de apenas rejeitar os `null`s com exceções podemos substituí-los pelos objetos vazios:

```
public void cadastrarNome(String nome) {
    String nomeParaCadastrar = nome == null ? "Sem nome" : nome;
    // ... Resto do método.
}
```

Esta abordagem tem a vantagem que, diferente da anterior, os erros referentes ao uso inadequado de `null` tendem de fato a desaparecer ao invés de apenas se moverem. Entretanto, nem sempre esta abordagem é possível ou adequada.

E agora, vamos dar uma olhada melhor no padrão de projeto *Null Object*. A ideia é que você represente os conceitos de "vazio", "não existe", "não encontrado", etc. com uma instância de um objeto, ao invés de usar o `null` para isso. Eis aqui um exemplo dessa abordagem:

```
public class Pessoa {
    private String nome;
    private int idade;

    // ... Métodos.

    // Método que retorna um Null Object.
    public static Pessoa ninguem() {
        Pessoa naoTem = new Pessoa();
        naoTem.nome = "Ninguém";
        naoTem.idade = 0;
        return naoTem;
    }
}

public class Carro {
    private String modelo;
    private String cor;
    private int ano;
    private Pessoa proprietario;

    // ... Métodos.

    // Método que retorna um Null Object.
    public static Carro vazio() {
        Carro carroVazio = new Carro();
        carroVazio.modelo = "nenhum";
        carroVazio.cor = "nenhuma";
        carroVazio.ano = 0;
        carroVazio.proprietario = Pessoa.ninguem();
        return carroVazio;
    }
}
```

Se você puder trabalhar como interfaces, fica melhor para implementar o padrão *Null Object*:

```
public interface Animal {
    public String fazerBarulho();
}

public class Cachorro implements Animal {
    @Override
    public String fazerBarulho() {
        return "Au au";
    }
}

public class Gato implements Animal {
    @Override
    public String fazerBarulho() {
        return "Miau";
    }
}

public class AnimalNenhum implements Animal {
    @Override
    public String fazerBarulho() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Novamente, vale frisar que você pode adotar uma destas abordagens para evitar o `null` **se possível**. Entretanto, nem sempre uma delas é possível e é comum aparecerem algumas situações aonde realmente deve-se retornar `null` ou aceitar que algum campo, parâmetro ou variável local possa ser `null` em circunstâncias normais, e você tem que saber conviver com isso. Saber conviver com os `null`s quando eles aparecerem sem causar um `NullPointerException` faz parte do que o programador Java deve fazer.

No final, todas as formas de se evitar o `NullPointerException` recaem em organizar a lógica do seu programa de modo a evitar cair em alguma das situações aonde ele possa aparecer. E em quase todas as situações aonde um `NullPointerException` aparece, ele deverá ser tratado como um erro de programação (como de fato quase sempre é): entenda porque ele ocorre e corrija o código para não mais ocorrer.

---

Por fim, vale a pena recomendar o [***SpotBugs***](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs), sucessor do famoso *FindBugs*. Trata-se de uma excelente e poderosa ferramenta de análise de código Java, capaz de detectar uma grande quantidade de erros de lógica, bugs, situações perigosas e más práticas de programação. E tudo isso obviamente inclui muitas situações que podem resultar em `NullPointerException`.

E se você for usar o *SpotBugs* (ou alguma outra ferramentas de verificação de código com características semelhantes), talvez você encontre uma anotação `@NotNull`, `@NonNull` ou `@Nonnull`, juntamente com alguma anotação `@Null`, `@Nullable` ou `@CheckForNull`. Várias pessoas de vários projetos diferentes criaram várias versões destas anotações com propósitos similares (o que é ruim, pois seria bem melhor se houvesse um único `@NotNull` canônico e um único `@Nullable` canônico). Você pode utilizar estas anotações em campos, variáveis, parâmetros e métodos para dizer para as ferramentas capazes de entendê-las que um `null` em determinado lugar é explicitamente proibido ou permitido. O *SpotBugs* é capaz de entender tais anotações, embora ele não necessite delas (mas se estiverem presentes, ele poderá fazer uma análise ainda mais profunda).

Uma outra ferramenta poderosa é o [***Checker Framework***](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/), que usa uma abordagem baseada em anotações (entre elas o `@NonNull` e o `@Nullable`) e funciona como um processador de anotações plugável diretamente no compilador. Com ele, é possível até mesmo transformar alguns locais onde poderia ocorrer um `NullPointerException` em erros de compilação, evitando a dor-de-cabeça de ter que rastreá-los em testes e/ou *debugging*.

Comment: Não seria melhor apenas contornar o problema do `NullPointerException` (i.e. pedindo a reentrada dos dados), ao invés de lançar outra exceção?

Comment: @Patrick, às vezes sim, você poderia colocar isso dentro do `while` e só deixar sair quando o dado for diferente de `null`. Mas na prática, essa situação específica de pedir a reentrada dos dados é rara. O grande negócio aqui é: 1. Saber e entender porque que o `null` surgiu em cada caso particular. 2. Saber se é válido ele de fato surgir e corrigir o código caso não seja. 3. Se ele for de fato válido, corrigir o código para tratá-lo adequadamente. No fim tudo acaba recaindo em projetar a lógica do programa de forma a garantir que todos os `null`s sejam manipulados de forma segura.

Answer (score 15):

A exceção [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) é lançada quando se tenta usar um objecto que não tenha sido ainda instanciado.

Tendo como base este classe:

```
public class Endereco{
    public String rua;
    public String localidade;

    public Endereco(String rua, String localidade){
        this.rua = rua;
        this.localidade = localidade;
    }
    public String getMoradaCompleta(){
        return rua + "," + localidade;
    }
}
```

As situações mais usuais são as seguintes:

1 - Chamar um método de instância de um objeto não instanciado.

```
public printMoradaCompleta(Endereco endereco){
    String morada = endereco.getMoradaCompleta();
    System.out.println(morada);
}
```

2 - Acessar ou modificar um campo  de um objeto não instanciado.

```
public printRua(Endereco endereco){
    String rua = endereco.rua;  
    System.out.println(rua);
}
```

3 - Acessar ou modificar um elemento de um array que não tenha sido inicializado.

```
public int getSecondElementFromArray(int[] array){

    return array[1];
}
```

Nas situações 1 e 2 os métodos irão falhar se o `endereco` passado for `null`.
Na situação 3 o método falhará caso `array` seja `null` ou não tenha sido atribuído nenhum valor ao  segundo elemento do array.

A forma de prevenir estas situações é verificar se o parâmetro passado ao método não é nulo e caso seja lançar uma `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
public printMoradaCompleta(Endereco endereco){
    if(endereco == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("O endereço não pode ser nulo");
    }
    String morada = endereco.getMoradaCompleta();
    System.out.println(morada);
}
```

[Aqui](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-nullpointerexception-how-to-handle-null-pointer-exception/) pode ser encontrado um artigo mais completo sobre o assunto:

Comment: Só queria te dizer que nomes de variáveis e de métodos deveriam iniciar com letra minúscula, seguindo as convenções de nomes do Java (até a coloração de sintaxe aqui é afetada por isso). Além disso, falta um `+` no seu método `MoradaCompleta` na classe `Endereco` para que ele possa compilar, mas abaixo você usa `getMoradaCompleta` ao invés de `MoradaCompleta`.

Comment: Por fim, a sua resposta se limita a verificar se os parâmetros de um método são nulos e lançar um `IllegalArgumentException` se for. Mas há muito mais além disso a ser feito para evitar o `NullPointerException`. Aqui você estaria apenas trocando o `NullPointerException` por um `IllegalArgumentException` no parâmetro de um método, o que provavelmente não resolve o problema principal da maioria dos iniciantes que usam Java, que é de não saber ao certo quando uma referência é nula ou não.

Comment: Agradeço os seus comentários. Todo o código foi escrito diretamente na caixa de resposta não tendo ajuda a corretor de sintaxe. Além disso os trechos de código são exemplificativos e neste caso não é relevante se compilam pelas razões que apontou. É claro que devemos sempre ter cuidado para evitar que erros como esses ocorram. A resposta poderia, de fato, ser mais completa mas tornar-se-ia muito extensa, daí o link ao artigo. Aguardo com expectativa que poste uma resposta que de certo irá complementar/superar a minha.

Comment: @ramaral não leve a mau. Mas, seu código está fora dos padrões do java como já foi citado e realmente, ele não compila. Você não poderia editar e arrumar ele ?

Comment: @wryel Editado.

Comment: Acabei de me deparar com uma situação onde dando um `get` em um `Boolean` me retornou também.

Answer (score 10):

Essa exceção é lançada sempre que se tentar acessar um objeto que ainda não foi inicializado.

O que pode lançar a exceção:

- Acessar métodos de objetos nulos.
- Acessar ou modificar campos de objetos nulos.
- Pegar o `length` de um `null`
- Acessar ou modificar os slots de um `null`
- Lançar uma exceção como se fosse 'lançável'

Em Java, é necessário sempre fazer duas coisas com qualquer objeto:

- Declarar o objeto;
- Inicializar o objeto (definir um valor diferente de null) - isso evita o `NullPointerException`

**Ex comuns:**

1º caso:

```
ArrayList<String> texto = null; //definido como null
texto.add("texto");
```

2º caso: // pense que a classe pessoa já foi criada com o atributo nome e o get/set

```
Pessoa p;
System.out.Println(p.getNome());
```

3º caso:

```
ArrayList<String> texto = null;
int i = texto.length;
```

4º caso:

```
Pessoa p = new Pessoa("maria");
Pessoa pessoas[] = null; 
pessoas[0] = p;
```

Em todos os casos, o que faltou?

INICIALIZAR O OBJETO (sem `null`)!!

Fonte: [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

Comment: Acho que as frases "Declarar o objeto" e "Inicializar o objeto" podem estar confusas ou até mesmo erradas, no contexto que você colocou, pois o que é declarado é a **variável de referência**, que quando inicializada corretamente está referenciando um objeto na memória. Objetos por sua vez não são declarados, são instanciados e podem estar sendo ou não referenciados por variáveis.

Comment: Na verdade, instancias de classes e variáveis são objetos, não? Se estou me referindo aos dois (classes e variáveis), como posso escolher entre declarar e instanciar?

Comment: Posso estar sendo detalhista, mas objeto e variável são coisas distintas. Por exemplo o `p` em `Pessoa p;` é uma variável, não um objeto. Da mesma forma que é possível criar um objeto sem declarar uma variável para referencia-lo, assim: `new Pessoa().getNome();`.

Comment: Esta sendo detalhista hehe mas ficou difícil de entender o que eu quis dizer? Se ficou mudo lá, mas não acho que deva ser crucificada por isso :P Até o/

Comment: Com certeza não deve ser sacrificada, rs.. senão já teria levado vários negativos. Só estou deixando claro um ponto da sua resposta potencialmente impreciso. A resposta é sua, mude se achar que deve ;-)

Answer (score 10):

## O que é NullPointerException?

> NullPointerException é uma exceção lançada quando se tenta acessar membros de um objeto que não existe.

Ou seja, o código presume que uma determinada variável referencia uma instância de um objeto e tenta acessar membros desta instância; então, quando não há instância de fato (a variável aponta para *null* em vez de referenciar um objeto), uma *NullPointerException* será lançada.

Veja:

```
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
```

No código acima, a variável *pessoa* referencia um objeto - ela referencia uma instância de *Pessoa*.

```
Pessoa pessoa = null;
```

E no código acima a variável *pessoa* não referencia nenhum objeto. Podemos dizer que ela "aponta para null" mas o mais usual é dizermos que "a variável é null".

Se você passar para um método qualquer esta variável que é *null* e este método tentar acessar um membro do objeto que ele presume existir, será lançada uma *NullPointerException*:

```
public void processaPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
    int idade = pessoa.getIdade(); //se pessoa é null, aqui será lançada uma NullPointerException.
    ... 
}
```

## Quais são as principais causas de NullPointerException?

Esta exceção ocorre basicamente por dois motivos:

> a) Erro de programação.
>
> b) Erro de utilização de uma biblioteca ou framework.

Uma *NullPointerException* lançada pelo seu código é um erro de programação que você cometeu. E se ela for lançada pelo código de uma biblioteca ou framework de terceiros, não é necessariamente um erro de programação deles - é mais provável que você esteja utilizando a biblioteca da maneira errada (deixou de configurar algo ou configurou da maneira errada, por exemplo).

## Que métodos ou práticas podem ser utilizadas para se prevenir de NullPointerException?

Para se prevenir desta exceção você deve evitar cometer erros de programação.

Por que é um erro de programação se o teu código lançar uma *NullPointerException*? Porque se isso acontecer então você escreveu um código para ser utilizado de um jeito e o está usando de outro jeito.

Considere este método:

```
public void processaPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
    // ... não importa o código que tem aqui.
}
```

O método acima jamais deveria lançar uma *NullPointerException* por *pessoa* ser *null* porque você jamais deveria passar uma variável *null* para ele!

A assinatura do método (seu nome e o parâmetro que ele espera) deixa muito óbvio que ele precisa de um objeto do tipo *Pessoa* para funcionar. Passar uma variável null para este método é um erro de programação.

Tratar no começo do método se a variável é *null* pode ajudar a diagnosticar o erro de programação mas eu considero uma prática ruim pois o código ficará sujo com validações que não são expressivas para o negócio.

Estas são validações expressivas para o negócio:

```
public void processaPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
    if (pessoa.getIdade() < 18) {
      throw new BusinessException("A pessoa precisa ser maior de idade para poder ser processada");
    }
    if (pessoa.getNotificacao() == null) {
      throw new BusinessException("A pessoa precisa ter sido notificada antes de ser processada.");
    }
    ... 
}
```

Já esta outra é uma validação ruim pois está sujando o código com instruções que não tem nada a ver com o negócio:

```
public void processaPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
    if (pessoa == null) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentExcetion("O parâmetro 'pessoa' não pode ser null.");
    }
    ... 
}
```

Este tipo de validação por vezes é defendida por facilitar o diagnóstico de erros, mas não é muito mais difícil perceber que pessoa é *null* simplesmente deixando estourar uma *NullPointerException* mais abaixo. Então eu opto por manter o código mais limpo e expressivo e não faço este tipo de validação.

Validações como esta devem ser feitas nos níveis mais altos da aplicação, na entrada de dados. Por exemplo:

```
// usuário entrou com o CPF da pessoa que ele quer processar

Pessoa pessoa = pessoas.find(cpf);
if (pessoa == null) {
    throw EntityNotFoundException("Não foi localizada nenhuma pessoa com o CPF " + cpf);
}
processaPessoa(pessoa);
```

#### Um erro comum ao tentar prevenir NullPointerException

Por ingenuidade ou por alguma característica não virtuosa, há programadores que se livram de NullPointerException assim:

```
public void processaPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
    if (pessoa != null) {
        // código para processar a pessoa.
    } // fim do método
}
```

O método acima nunca vai falhar por pessoa ser *null*, mas o sistema provavelmente vai falhar e vai ser do pior jeito possível: silenciosamente.

Todo mundo vai ficar achando que alguém foi processado mas isso não ocorreu e nenhum alerta foi dado.

Então a *NullPointerException* foi evitada ao custo do sistema ter sua integridade corrompida.

## Conclusão

NullPointerException é uma exceção lançada quando se tenta acessar membros de um objeto que não existe.

A maneira de evitá-la **não** é validando no começo do método se os argumentos são *null* (pelo menos não na maioria das vezes).

A maneira de evitá-la é validando a entrada de dados nos níveis mais altos da aplicação (entradas do usuário, valores nos arquivos de configuração, fachada de serviços para consumo externo, etc.) e escrevendo código expressivo para que os seus consumidores saibam como consumi-lo.

Além disso, algumas vezes é válido no domínio que um objeto não exista (veja mais acima o exemplo da pessoa que não pôde ser processada porque não tinha sido notificada). Nestes casos, a existência do objeto deve ser validada antes de ele ser utilizado para que tenhamos um erro expressivo para o negócio em vez de termos uma *NullPointerException*.

Por fim, bibliotecas e frameworks lançam *NullPointerException* quando são utilizadas da maneira incorreta.

Quando uma *NullPointerException* é lançada por bibliotecas ou frameworks (pelo servidor de aplicativos, por exemplo) ficamos muito irados porque queríamos que eles tivessem validado os parâmetros e tivessem lançado um erro mais expressivo. Mas, como eu disse, geralmente é mais difícil descobrir por que uma variável chegou nula até ali do que simplesmente identificar que um determinado parâmetro é null.

Answer (score 4):

Esse erro ocorre sempre quando eu tento captar uma informação que não teve valor atribuído.

Exemplo:

Vc tem no seu BEAN a class Cliente.

No seu main da classe principal você instância Cliente

```
Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
```

O erro ocorre quando por exemplo você vai imprimir o código do cliente.

```
System.out.println(cliente.getCodigo);
```

(Perceba que em nenhum momento atribuímos valor ao código do cliente, então o compilador vai exibir o erro `NullPointerException`, você está tentando imprimir algo vazio).

atribua o valor a `cliente.setCodigo(1);`
depois imprima normalmente vai funcionar.

CORREÇÃO: 
Essa exceção não vai ser apresentada no println (pois ele consegue tratar informações null).
O problema mesmo seria atribuir o valor a um jtextfiel, exemplo: seuTextField.setText(cliente.getCodigo());
//O erro vai acontecer pois não temos nada atribuído ao código do cliente.

Comment: Votei negativo pelos seguintes motivos: `Cliente cliente = new Cliente(); System.out.println(cliente.getCodigo);` imprimiria `null`. Não dá `NullPointerException`. O `System.out.println` não tem problema em receber `null`, então não daria nenhum problema em tentar imprimir vazio. Dizer que o compilador lança o `NullPointerException` é absurdo, quem o lançaria seria a JVM. Além disso você esqueceu os parênteses após o `getCodigo`.

Comment: Verdade @victor-stafusa, o problema ocorre não quando vamos imprimir no println, mas quando vamos por exemplo atribuir a informação a um jTextFiel. (Exemplo: seuTextField.setText(cliente.getCod());  ) #desculpas

Answer (score 0):

Em Java, toda variável ou constante precisa de uma instância para que possa ser utilizada, supondo que temos uma classe Usuario, e passamos o nome no construtor:

```
Usuario usuarioVariavel = new Usuario("João");
usuarioVariavel = new Usuario("Felipe");
```

No exemplo acima, a variável "usuarioVariavel" estava com a instância de nome "João", depois foi atribuído uma nova instância de nome "Felipe", esquecendo "João"

NullPointerException é o acesso de um método ou atributo de uma variável que não possui instância

Por exemplo:

```
Usuario usuario = null;
int idade = usuario.getIdade(); //Gera NullPointerException
```

O melhor jeito de se previnir é a verificação se o objeto possui instância (diferente de nulo), por exemplo:

```
if(usuario!=null){
     int idade = usuario.getIdade();
     //...
}
```

Outro jeito, mas de menor desempenho (visto que quando uma exceção é lançada o Java tem que buscar informações sobre ela) é o tratamento da exceção:

```
try{
    int idade = usuario.getIdade();
}catch(NullPointerException npe){
    //Usuário não possui instância
}
```

Muitas vezes podemos evitar o NullPointerException quando o acesso de um método  ou atributo não precisa ser obrigatoriamente de uma instância específica, mas sim, a classe em si guarda um determinado valor, onde todos que chamarem tal classe podem usar o método ou atributo, para isso definimos o método e/ou atributo como "static"

```
public class Usuario{
   private static int quantidadeUsuarios = 0;
   public static int getQuantidadeUsuarios(){
        return quantidadeUsuarios;
   } 
}
```

E chamasse:

```
int quantidade = Usuario.getQuantidadeUsuarios();  
//Não gera NullPointerException, porque o método não pertence à uma instância específica
```