# java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, java-ee, nullpointerexception

Classe principal apresentando problema na chamada do método criarNovaConta e inserirCliente:

```
        case 1:
            cliente = new Cliente();

            cliente.setNome(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nome: "));

            cliente.setCpf(Long.parseLong(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Cpf: ")));

            try {
                cliente.criaNovaConta();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        null,
                        "Nome: " + cliente.getNome() + "\nCpf: "
                                + cliente.getCpf()
                                + "\nNúmero da conta corrente: "
                                + cliente.conta.getNumeroConta());
            } catch (RuntimeException re) {
                System.out.println("Erro ao gerar número de conta: " + re);
            }

            try {
                banco.inserirCliente(cliente);
            } catch (RuntimeException re) {
                System.out.println("Erro ao inserir novo cliente: " + re);
            }

            break;
```

Os métodos da minha classe Cliente:

```
 public ContaBancaria conta;

 public Cliente() {
   }

 public void criaNovaConta() {
    conta = new ContaBancaria();
    conta.setNumeroConta();
}
```

O método da minha classe Conta Bancaria referente ao problema:

```
public void setNumeroConta() {
    boolean achou = false;
    int nConta = aleatorio.nextInt(10000) + 99999;

    for (Cliente c : banco.clientes) {
        if (c.conta.numeroConta == nConta) {
            achou = true;
        }
    }
    if (achou) {
        setNumeroConta();
    } else {
        this.numeroConta = nConta;
    }
}
```

O método da minha classe Banco referente ao problema:

```
List<Cliente> clientes;

public void inserirCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        clientes.add(cliente);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conta cadastrada com sucesso!");
    }
```

Comment: Provavelmente você não associou uma `conta` ao cliente. Você deveria fazer `cliente.setConta(new Conta())`, e em seguida `cliente.getConta().setNumeroConta()`, ou algo assim.

Comment: Como está sua classe `Cliente` e `Conta` ??

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: [O que é a NullPointerException e quais são suas principais causas?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63617/3117)

Answer (score 5):

Observe o código abaixo:

```
cliente = new Cliente();

cliente.setNome(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nome: "));

cliente.setCpf(Long.parseLong(JOptionPane
        .showInputDialog("Cpf: ")));

try {
    cliente.conta.setNumeroConta();
```

Cria-se um cliente que inicialmente terá o campo `conta` como `null`. Depois você tenta acessar um método do campo `conta` que é `null`. O resultado é um `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Altere o construtor da sua classe **Cliente** para sempre criar uma instância da **ContaBancaria** junto.

```
public class Cliente {

    // seus atributos

    public Cliente() {
        this.conta = new ContaBancaria();
    }

    // Generate Getters e Setters
}
```

Outra sugestão é trocar o atributo `conta` para *private* e criar seu respectivo get/set.