# Erro: 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)'

Tags: java, android

Este é um programa, que por traz da calculadora, guarda arquivos que julgue importantes. O campo de mensagem do erro creio que não seja dele e sim do Super SU ou do sistema Android, pois toda vez, em qualquer programa que tenha que ter um acesso mais profundo ele abre o mesmo estilo de campo dizendo que concedeu permissão. Porém desta vez um erro ocorreu. Alguém poderia me auxiliar a resolver este problema?

[image: screenshot no celular]

Comment: mas está a desenvolver essa aplicação? Ou é um erro de alguma aplicação que já exista?

Comment: Coloque o seu código cara, desse jeito sua pergunta ira receber downvotes e será fechada. Outra coisa você está comparando um boolean com um Object?

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino nesse caso boolean é o tipo de retorno do método equals.

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino o `boolean` é da função `equals`

Comment: Não entendi direito então, achei que fosse outra coisa não o retorno dele. hahaha

Comment: O seu problema se chama `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Veja mais aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63736/132

Answer (score 2):

O erro informado por você indica que em alguma parte do seu código você esta fazendo `str1.equals(str2);` sendo que `str1` é um objeto nulo, ou seja, você esta fazendo referencia a um objecto nulo.

verifique em seu código os lugares em que você está usando o método `equals` para encontrar onde está seu erro.

Exemplo que dará o erro:

```
String str1 = null;
String str2 = "teste";
boolean ret = str1.equals(str2);
```