# Não estou a conseguir aceder a um WebService escrito em C#, a partir de Java

Tags: java, c#, web-service, wsdl

Tenho um WebService escrito C# e preciso de me conectar a ele a partir de Java para invocar uns métodos.

É possível?

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;


public class SoapClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        URL wsdlLocation = null;
        try {
            wsdlLocation = new URL("http://localhost:8000/eamsLink/RepositoryService/?wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SoapClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


        QName qname = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "RemoteSourceService");

        Service service = Service.create(wsdlLocation, qname);
    }
}
```

Estou a tentar desta maneira mas estou a ter este erro na consola:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.wsdl.WSDLOperationImpl.freeze(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.wsdl.WSDLPortTypeImpl.freeze(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.wsdl.WSDLBoundPortTypeImpl.freeze(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.wsdl.WSDLModelImpl.freeze(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Unknown Source)
    at SoapClient.main(SoapClient.java:22)
```

Comment: [**O que é `NullPointerException` e quais suas principais causas?**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63736/4808)

Comment: @renan não está nada a null. Já verifiquei o objecto inteiro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recomendo utilizar JAX WS e CXF para fazer chamadas a WebService em java é bem mais simples.

[Link exemplo - Usando Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcreate_client.html)

Caso contrário, se não estiver utilizando IDE do Eclipse, pode ser executado gerando os stubs da classe baseado no wsdl e então executar como se fosse em .NET.

Execute este comando no prompt, onde está o código fonte do seu consumidor.

> wsimport -keep -p com.acme.client http://localhost:8000/eamsLink/RepositoryService/?wsdl

Troque **com.acme.client** para o seu pacote.

Neste caso o wsimport deve gerar algumas classes .java no local, conforme a especificação do seu serviço, desta forma, deve ter um aquivo ImplService.java e você dever fazer a instanciação deste serviço e a chamada do seu método, pode ser visto um exemplo www.thejavageek.com/2015/01/28/using-wsimport-command-generate-web-service-client.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: ja mudei de estratégia. Vou ter de criar uma "Gateway" entre o Java e o C# WebService. Servindo o Java e a Gateway como servidor e cliente, cada uma. Consegue-me ajudar aqui?

Comment: Pode me explicar melhor a sua necessidade? Ira criar um gateway ou proxy para o webservice em c#? Ficará assim Java -> Gateway (Java) -> Webservice?

Comment: podemos falar em algum chat?