# Excepção no Thread "Main" java.land.NullPointerException em com.Login.Login.mai(Login.java:18)

Tags: java, array, nullpointerexception

Hoje eu tentei fazer um sistema de login (de novo), só que desta vez usei um *array* unidimensional para guardar meus valores. Quando executei o meu programa, o Eclipse acusou um erro (ponteiro nulo para ser mais específico), minha teoria é que atribuir um valor ao *array* causou o erro.

Segue abaixo meu código:

```
package com.Login;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Login {
    Random r = new Random();

    String[] valores;
    boolean isSessionValid;
    int sessID = r.nextInt();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Login log = new Login();


        System.out.println("Digite o nome do usuário:");
        log.valores[1] = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Digite sua senha:");
        log.valores[2] = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Digite novamente a senha:");
        log.valores[3] = in.nextLine();
        if(log.valores[3].equals(log.valores[1])){
            System.out.println("Você está logado!");
            log.isSessionValid = true;
            System.out.println("Sua Sessão é:"+log.sessID);
        }
    }

}
```

Simplesmente o código atribui o nome de usuário a `log.valores[1]` e a senha a `log.valores[2]` e `log.valores[3]` serve somente para confirmar a senha.

Comment: Só uma pequena observação, vetores começam do indice 0, é bom se acostumar e se adaptar a isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse erro indica que está tentando acessar um objeto que não foi inicializado. Resolverá inicializando o vetor. Aparentemente 4 posições são suficientes. Talvez até 3 se começar pelo índice 0:

```
String[] valores = new String[4];
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/Initialization.java).

O código tem outras coisas ruins, mas vou me ater ao perguntado.

Veja mais em [O que é a NullPointerException e quais são suas principais causas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63617/101).

Comment: Vou fazer uma canônica sobre isto, todo dia tem uma pergunta sobre isto e é muito básico. Assim é melhor fechar como duplicata. Este é praticamente um erro de digitação (ainda que tecnicamente não seja).

Comment: Estava com o dedo no publicar quando a notificação da sua resposta apareceu kkkk

Comment: Obrigado a todos :D