# Erro NullPointerException ao chamar um método

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

```
public void addFormaPagamento() {
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            boolean isInsertForma = dbApp.insertFormaPagamento(
                    spnForma.getSelectedItemPosition(),
                    spnParcelas.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                    edtvalor.getText().toString()
            );

            if (isInsertForma == true) {
                verifica_Add_Forma += 1;
                Toast.makeText(ActDetalheCheckout.this, "Forma de Pagamento Inserida com Sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ActDetalheCheckout.this, "Falha os Inserir Forma de pagamento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Está dando um erro nessa linha:

```
boolean isInsertForma = dbApp.insertFormaPagamento(
```

Erro apresentado:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: maijava.lang.NullPointerException
at app.teste1.ActDetalheCheckout$1.onClick(ActDetalheCheckout.java:65
```

Comment: Antes de chamar um método de um objecto é necessário instanciar a classe.

Comment: Onde estás a instanciar o dbApp?

Comment: Somente com o código mostrado não tem como adivinhar qual dos objetos é nulo. Sugiro colocar cada um desses objetos em variáveis e acompanhar seus valores pelo depurador.

Comment: Só com este pedaço de código não dá pra ter certeza de qual parte está causando o NullPointer. Pode significar que algum dos parâmetros que está passando para o método `insertFormaPagamento()` é null ou que `dbApp` é null ou pode ter outra causa. Sugiro que tente debugar seu código, adicione um breakpoint na linha do erro e verifique o valor de todos os argumentos e acompanhe a execução do programa passo a passo.

Comment: Galera, consegui arrumar. Eu tinha me esquecido de instanciar o objeto "dbApp", conforme o ramaral e o Jorge haviam falado. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @GabrielSouza Você pode postar abaixo a resposta da sua própria pergunta, ai talvez se algum dia alguém tiver o mesmo problema, já verá sua resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre quando lança uma exceção de NullPointerException significa que está tentando acessar um objeto e/ou variável nulo.

No teu caso está chamando o insertFormaPagamento do objeto dbApp que não deve estar instanciado.

Ou coloca um teste antes para ver se dbApp != null, ou verifica o pq ele não está sendo instanciado.

Comment: *"Sempre quando lança uma exceção de NullPointerException significa que está tentando chamar um método de um objeto vazio."* -  apesar de não estar totalmente errado, isso da margem a interpretações equivocadas. O [NullPointerException](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63736/28595) ocorre quando se tenta acessar um objeto e/ou variavel nulo. Nem sempre um "objeto vazio" está nulo.

Comment: Boa Diego, isso aí.

Comment: Sugiro que edite a resposta corrigindo esta afirmação, para que não dê margem de erro no entendimento.

Comment: _"Sugiro que edite a resposta corrigindo esta afirmação, para que não dê margem de erro no entendimento."_ - Feito.