# erro :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Estou tentando dar um set em um atributo que é um vetor, e que está em uma classe `y`, porém estou tenho uma classe `x`, que é composta por essa classe `y`.

Na hora que escrevo o código não dá nenhum erro, porém ao executar o seguinte erro me aparece:

> erro: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   Pedido.leituraMassas(Pedido.java:80)

como posso resolver isto?

Classe y:[image: classe y]

Classe x:
[image: classe X]

Comment: Não poste imagens do código, poste o código em forma de texto, diretamente na pergunta.

Comment: Lucas não é boa ideia colocar imagens com código, só dificulta a vida a quem o quer ajudar, porque assim não consegue fazer copy/paste para testar o código. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5149/devemos-cortar-a-mania-das-perguntas-com-imagem-do-c%C3%B3digo-ao-inv%C3%A9s-do-c%C3%B3digo

Comment: Onde a variável `massas` está declarada? O que ela faz? Por favor poste o seu código inteiro, e pelo amor de Deus, poste o seu código como texto e não como imagens!

Comment: Veja isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63617/132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   Pedido.leituraMassas(Pedido.java:80)

significa que você está tentando fazer alguma operação em um objeto que está nulo! Costumo dizer que é o erro mais simples de ser corrigido no java, pois ele nos direciona exatamente para o tal objeto! ;)

No caso do seu código, o seu objeto "`massas`", na linha 80 da classe "Pedido"(Classe X) está nulo e você está tentando adicionar uma descrição nele.

Como não pude testar o seu código, posso apenas te dar a dica de inicializar o seu objeto antes de setar atributos nele.

Um simples `Massas massas = new Massas();` antes da linha 80 resolveria seu problema.

Comment: Boa tarde Dante,

Muito Obrigado pela informação, era isso mesmo.
Problema resolvido.

Me desculpe por não ter colocado o código, sou novo aqui e não sabia, mas na próxima já sei.

abraço!

Comment: De nada, cara! Marca minha resposta como correta e da um up? ;)