# Matriz Java: não recebe valor

Tags: java, matriz

Estou tendo um pequeno problema em relação uma matriz que estou tentando desenvolver para pegar coordenadas dentro de um `JFrame` e passá-las para posicionar os botões corretamente. Segue o código:

```
public class Coordenadas {

    //coordenadas
     int posicLinha;
     int posicColuna;
    //metodo para atribuir as coordenadas as devidas posições da matriz. 
    public void atribPosic (){
        Coordenadas[][] tabuleiro = new Coordenadas [8][8];//matriz de objetos coordenadas
        for (int l=0;l<8;l++){
            for (int c=0;c<8;c++){
                tabuleiro[l][c].posicLinha = 100+50*l;//primeira coordenada de linha, será igual a 100
                tabuleiro[l][c].posicColuna = 100+50*c;//primeira coordenada de coluna, será igual a 100
                System.out.print(tabuleiro[l][c].posicLinha);//imprime a coordenada da linha 
                System.out.print(tabuleiro[l][c].posicColuna);//imprime a coordenada da coluna
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[]args){
        Coordenadas coordenadas = new Coordenadas ();
        coordenadas.atribPosic();
    }
}
```

O meu problema é que, ele não imprime o valor devido à um erro na fórmula de atribuição de valor de coordenada. Gostaria de ajuda, não sei a causa deste erro.

Answer (score 3):

Você não diz na pergunta qual é o erro. O que você está tendo é um `NullPointerException`. As fórmulas de atribuição que você uso não são o problema e estão corretas.

O motivo de dar erro é porque a matriz é criada inicialmente contendo `null` em todas as posições. E quando você faz `tabuleiro[l][c].posicLinha`, `tabuleiro[l][c]` vai ser `null` e tentar acessar o `posicLinha` de `null` dará `NullPointerException`.

A solução mais simples e mais fácil para esse seu problema é acrescentar isso no começo do `for` interno:

```
tabuleiro[l][c] = new Coordenadas();
```

Isso vai fazer o seu código executar, mas ele ainda não vai imprimir o que você quer, pois você dá um `print` em um número, dá um outro `print` logo em seguida sem adicionar espaço, nem quebra de linha e nem nada fazendo os números ficarem colados, e para cada coordenada você vai fazendo isso fazendo todos os números ficarem colados uns nos outros formando um único linguição de dígitos no final em uma única linha sem espaços nem vírgulas e nem nada no meio. Ao usar o que está abaixo, isso é resolvido:

```
System.out.println(tabuleiro[l][c].posicLinha + ", " + tabuleiro[l][c].posicColuna);
```

Com essas duas correções, o seu código se comportará como esperado. Entretanto, o seu código ainda sofre de outros problemas estruturais, embora funcione mesmo assim (mas provavelmente vai quebrar se você for fazer alguma alteração). Observe que para criar a matriz você usa uma instância vazia e inútil de `Coordenadas` que só existe para que você possa chamar o método `atribPosic`. Isso pode ser resolvido por meio do uso do modificador `static` no método, dispensando a necessidade de existir uma instância para utilizá-lo.

Também não colocar modificadores de visibilidade nos seus campos/atributos não costuma ser boa ideia. Dificilmente você pretendia usar a visibilidade de pacote. Além disso, nomes de classes devem preferencialmente ser substantivos no singular, e portanto `Coordenada` seria um nome melhor que `Coordenadas`.

Também não há necessidade ou finalidade em se "comer" algumas letras dos nomes de variáveis e métodos, e portanto `atribuirPosicao` é melhor que `atribPosic`. O mesmo vale para `posicLinha` e `posicColuna` que poderiam ficar `posicaoLinha` e `posicaoColuna`, mas simplesmente `linha` e `coluna` é mais simples.

O seu código com essas correções e alterações todas fica assim:

```
public class Coordenada {

    private int linha;
    private int coluna;

    public static void atribuirPosicao() {
        Coordenada[][] tabuleiro = new Coordenada[8][8];
        for (int l = 0; l < 8; l++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
                tabuleiro[l][c] = new Coordenada();
                tabuleiro[l][c].linha = 100 + 50 * l;
                tabuleiro[l][c].coluna = 100 + 50 * c;
                System.out.println(tabuleiro[l][c].linha + ", " + tabuleiro[l][c].coluna);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Coordenada.atribuirPosicao();
    }
}
```

Por fim, recomendo que veja [essa outra resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63736/132) que postei [nessa outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63617/132) para entender quais são as causas de um `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Consegui consertar o erro. Era coisa boba. Valeu!