# Qual a diferença entre usar Object.toString() e String.valueOf()?

Tags: java

Estava fazendo uns testes e percebi que utilizar um ou outro, o resultado acaba sendo o mesmo. Fiz este código para exemplificar:

```
public class ParseToStringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ParseToStringTest().parseTest();
    }

    public void parseTest() {

        SomeObj o = new SomeObj();
        System.out.println(o.toString());
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(o));

    }

    class SomeObj {}
}
```

Rodando no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/exXf4B), o resultado que obtive foi:

```
Ideone$SomeObj@677327b6
Ideone$SomeObj@677327b6
```

Ou seja, o resultado foi idêntico.

Teria alguma diferença entre usar [`String#valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object))  ou [`Object#toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) para exibir uma representação do objeto em forma de String?

Comment: https://books.google.com.br/books?id=CsGtipt1wsQC&pg=PA330&lpg=PA330&dq=diferen%C3%A7a+entre+usar+Object.toString()+e+String.valueOf()?&source=bl&ots=ow7LMsxLf7&sig=puZzLbqAAuaKAguO3dzstM0dZGY&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX_IGxrZXUAhVKOZAKHWFXA38Q6AEITTAG#v=onepage&q=diferen%C3%A7a%20entre%20usar%20Object.toString()%20e%20String.valueOf()%3F&f=false

Comment: O `.toString()` lança NPE, `String.valueOf()` não

Comment: Também o `String.valueOf()` verifica por nulos, portanto pode ter algum overhead na aplicação

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Na [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-) diz que "*se o argumento é nulo é retornado `null`, caso contrário o valor retorna `.toString`*". Segundo essa lágica, o `String.valueOf(Object)` imprime *null* enquanto o `Object.toString()` pode gerar um [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Um outro detalhe importante é que o `valueOf` é um método estático, já o `toString` é um método de instância e só pode ser chamado em um tipo de referência. No entanto, o `valueOf` talvez, digo talvez, seja mais flexível em relação ao `toString()`. Veja os tipos básicos do método estático `valueOf`, que pode ser invocado:

```
String   valueOf(boolean b) 
String   valueOf(char c) 
String   valueOf(char[] data) 
String   valueOf(char[] data, int offset, int count) 
String   valueOf(double d) 
String   valueOf(float f) 
String   valueOf(int i) 
String   valueOf(long l) 
String   valueOf(Object obj)
```

Se tratando do `toString()`, sempre será necessário fazer a chamada de sua classe específica. Veja um exemplo:

```
Integer.toString(int i)   // inteiros
Float.toString(float f);  // flutuantes
```

Veja estes exemplos:

**Exemplo 1:**

```
public String doIt(float number) {

  return String.valueOf(number);
}
```

**Exemplo 2:**

```
public String doIt(float number) {

  return Float.toString(number);
}
```

Comment: Boa explicação.

Answer (score 17):

## [**Documentação da Oracle**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-)

> if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the
> value of obj.toString() is returned.

**Tradução:**

> Se o argumento é null, então temos uma string igual a "null"; Caso
> contrário, o valor de *`obj.toString()`* é retornado.

*Traduzido em código seria:*

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

No caso de um `Object#toString`, se a instância é `null` um [*NullPointerException*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63617/o-que-%C3%A9-a-nullpointerexception-e-quais-s%C3%A3o-suas-principais-causas/63736) será lançado. Não deve haver  uma diferença exceto para uma invocação de método adicional, ou seja, são praticamente a mesma coisa.

Comment: Um é a prova de NPE, o outro não: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208388/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-usar-object-tostring-e-string-valueof#comment426202_208388

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado você diz NullPointer? Acha que deveria acrescentar?

Comment: Mania: `NullPointerException` vulgo NPE pelas iniciais. Acho que você deveria botar isso na diferença entre os dois jeitos de transformar objeto em string

Comment: Afinal, ser protegido contra exceção eu creio que seja uma real diferença

Answer (score 13):

Quase nenhuma. Existe uma indireção adicional no `String.valueOf`, que é a checagem se o parâmetro é nulo ou não.

Parafraseando a [documentação de `String.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)):

O método vai checar se o objeto é nulo e, se ele for, é retornada a *string* `"null"`, caso contrário será feita a chamada de `.toString()` do objeto.

Em código, o `valueOf` é, basicamente:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return obj == null ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Ainda existem classes que implementam uma versão **estática de `toString()`** (como a [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int)) ou [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])), por exemplo), isso serve, principalmente, para que estas classes possam trabalhar numa versão alternativa da representação do objeto como `string`, permitindo parâmetros adicionais ou uma implementação personalizada independente do `.toString()` original.

Isso fica bem claro na classe `Integer`, onde existe um *overload* que é possível definir qual a base que o número será mostrado.

```
Integer number = 15;

System.out.println(Integer.toString(number, 10)); // 15   (decimal, base 10)
System.out.println(Integer.toString(number, 2));  // 1111 (binário, base 2)
System.out.println(Integer.toString(number, 16)); // f    (hexadecimal, base 16)
```

[Veja este exemplo funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/IWWV)

Então, o mais indicado é usar `String.valueOf` quando o objeto pode ser nulo, noutros casos, pode-se usar tranquilamente o `.toString()`.