# Problema em fazer TextView exibir valor atualizado

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, textview

Estou fazendo uma aplicação simples, é apenas um contador, com dois botões, "+"e"-", que consiste em exibir um valor inicial de 0, e se eu clicar em algum dos botões, o valor exibido na tela vai ser acrescido, ou decrementado, conforme o botão correspondente. 
Meu problema está em exibir o novo valor na tela. Eu pego o valor da TextView, faço as alterações, e por final, não consigo exibi-la na tela, o app simplesmente fecha.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btmais, btmenos, btmais2, btmenos2 ;
TextView pontuacao, pontuacao2;
EditText nome, nome2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btmais = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btmais);
    btmenos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btmenos);
    btmais2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btmais2);
    btmenos2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btmenos2);

    pontuacao = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pontuacao);
    pontuacao2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pontuacao2);

    btmais.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            int numero = Integer.parseInt( pontuacao.getText().toString() );
            numero = numero + 1;
            pontuacao.setText(numero);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Códigos xml:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="182dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pontuacao"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="100sp"
            tools:text="00" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btmais"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btmenos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nome2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pontuacao2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="01"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="100sp"
            tools:text="@string/pontuacao2" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btmais2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btmenos2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Muitos componente do layout ainda estão em desuso pois preciso primeiro fazer esse código funcionar, ele é a parte principal.

Agradeço muito a ajuda e atenção desde já

[image: Este é o layout]

Comment: Edite a pergunta e insira seu activity_main.xml nela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro você tem que declarar a variável `numero` globalmente fora do botão inicializando com `0`.

```
private int numero = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btmais.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            numero++;
        }
    });
}
```

Ai depois não insira um valor inteiro diretamente no método `setText()`. Use o método estático `valueOf` para converter primeiro para *string*. Veja como deve ficar:

```
pontuacao.setText(String.valueOf(numero));
```

Veja o resultado final:

```
final int numero = 0;
btmais.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        numero++;
        pontuacao.setText(String.valueOf(numero));
    }
});
```

Você pode usar também o método `toString()`. Veja nessa pergunta [qual a diferença entre usar Object.toString() e String.valueOf()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/208397/35406)?

Comment: Já tentei, continua do mesmo jeito. Rodo ele no celular, e aparece a notificação "O app pontuacao parou"

Comment: Mas aí tu declarastes uma constante, não dá pra mudar o valor dela, e é preciso que mude. Mas me ajudou bastante de qqr forma, muit obrigado.

Comment: Se quando você clicar no botão como está na resposta e alterar o valor do TextView, então não é constante, e sim variável. O numero++ incrementa 1 no valor que declarou fora do botão.

Comment: Mas o android studio me retorna "Cannot assign a value to final variable 'numero' "

Comment: @Igor editei a pergunta novamente, colocando fora do onCreate sem o 'final'...

Comment: @Igor o que você não pode mesmo fazer é colocar a variável inicializando dentro do botão, senão não poderás alterar em um outro caso dependendo a situação.