# NullPointerException ao chamar retorno do método em outra classe

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, nullpointerexception

Tenho o seguinte método na classe LoginController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/usuarioEntidade", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Resposta usuarioEntidade(@RequestBody EntidadesAdministradores usuarioEntidade) throws ServletException {
    EntidadesAdministradores entAdministradoresAutenticado = eaService.buscarUsuarioEntidade(usuarioEntidade.getUsuarioAdministrador());        
    usuarioEntidade = entAdministradoresAutenticado;
    Long us = usuarioEntidade.getEntidade().getIdEntidade();

    return new Resposta (us);
}

public class Resposta {
        public Long us;
        public Resposta(Long us) {
            this.us = us;
        }

        public Long getUs() {
            return us; 
        }
    }
```

Já debuguei e o retorno do método está vindo o que eu quero, um id do tipo `Long`.

Passando o retorno desse método , `us`, para a classe DistritoController, quando eu chamo a requisição `/distritos` tenho um erro de `java.lang.NullPointerException`

DistritoController

```
 @Autowired
    DistritosService distritosService; 
    Resposta resp; 

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/distritos", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Distritos>> buscarTodosDistritos(Long usuarioEntidade) throws ServletException { 
 usuarioEntidade = resp.getUs();
        Collection<Distritos> distritosBuscados = distritosService.buscarFiltro(usuarioEntidade);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(distritosBuscados, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: O stacktrace do `NullPointerException` aponta para a linha do `Collection<Distritos> distritosBuscados = distritosService.buscarFiltro(usuarioEntidade);`?

Comment: aponta para esta linha `controller.DistritosController.buscarTodosDistritos(DistritosController.java:44) ~[classes/:na]` que é `usuarioEntidade = resp.getUs();`

Comment: Ou seja, `resp` é `null`. Como é que a classe `LoginController` chama a `DistritoController`? Onde o `resp` poderia estar sendo setado?

Comment: Leitura útil: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63617/64969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A exceção acontece porque o seu atributo `resp` aparentemente está nulo.

Você poderia retornar o id do usuário logado diretamente, como no código abaixo:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/usuarioEntidade", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Long usuarioEntidade(@RequestBody EntidadesAdministradores usuarioEntidade) throws ServletException {
    EntidadesAdministradores entAdministradoresAutenticado = eaService.buscarUsuarioEntidade(usuarioEntidade.getUsuarioAdministrador());        
    usuarioEntidade = entAdministradoresAutenticado;
    return usuarioEntidade.getEntidade().getIdEntidade();
}
```

Com isso, você poderia guardar este id do usuário logado no seu cliente, em um `cookie` ou `localStorage` por exemplo.

E então, você poderia adaptar o método `buscarTodosDistritos()` do seu `DistritoController` para receber o id do usuário pela URL, [como recomenda a filosofia REST](https://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/distritos/{usuario}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Collection<Distritos>> buscarTodosDistritos(@PathVariable Long usuario) throws ServletException { 
    Collection<Distritos> distritosBuscados = distritosService.buscarFiltro(usuario);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(distritosBuscados, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Note que eu adicionei `/{usuario}` no final do *endpoint*, que representa o seu parâmetro `Long usuario` e o valor deste será passado através da URL.

Exemplo: `localhost:8080/api/distritos/1`, onde `1` deve ser o valor do id do seu usuário logado.