# Quando usar Collections.emptyList()?

Tags: java, collection

Eu pensei em utilizar

`List<Object> lista = Collections.emptyList();`

para inicializar uma lista. Mas quando tento fazer `lista.add(element)` recebo uma `UnsupportedOperationException`. Depois de pesquisar um pouco, vi que isso ocorre porque o objeto retornado por `Collections.emptyList()` 'e imutavel. Sendo assim, quando 'e apropriado utilizar  `Collections.emptyList()` em vez de

`List<Object> lista = new ArrayList<>();` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considere um método que retorna um `List<?>`, não é bonito (e nem faz sentido) retornar `null`, além de aumentar as chances de uma [`NullPointerException`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63617/4808) brotar na execução da sua aplicação. No mundo real, ou uma lista está cheia ou vazia, certo? Normalmente utiliza-se uma lista vazia como retorno, por exemplo:

```
public List<Pessoa> getPessoas(){
   List<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<>();

   if(hasSomeCondition()){
      // insere alguns objetos à lista 'pessoas'.
   }

   return pessoas;
}
```

O problema no exemplo acima é que sempre será criado um novo objeto para retorno, mesmo que vazio e isso pode ser custoso. Retornar uma `Collections.emptyList()` seria mais eficiente visto que esse método sempre retornará a mesma instância (singleton).

Sabendo que o método retorna uma lista sempre, mesmo que vazia, evita a checagem por `null`, por exemplo:

```
public List<Pessoa> getPessoas(){

   if(hasSomeCondition()){
      // Vai retornar uma lista preenchida cada a condição esteja ok.
   }

   return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

```
// Ao invés de:
List<Pessoa> pessoas = getPessoas();
if(pessoas != null){
   switch(pessoas.size()){
     // ...
   }
}
```

```
// Pode-se chamar sem medo:
switch(getPessoas().size()){
   // ...
}
```

Além disso, é *thread-safe* e não precisa se preocupar com o tipo do objeto genérico. Se o seu método retorna um `List<Foo>`, chamar `Collections.emptyList()` automaticamente lhe dará uma lista de `Foo` (o mesmo que retornar `Collections.<Foo>emptyList()`).