# Android - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo uma aplicação para enviar alguns caracteres por Bluetooth até um Arduíno, porém, não consigo guardar o endereço mac do módulo usado. 
O erro se dá exatamente aqui:

> EXTRA_ADDRESS = data.getExtras().getString(MAC_ADRESS);

```
MainActivity
package aluno.fabio.projetofresadora;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;


import static aluno.fabio.projetofresadora.ListaDispositivos.MAC_ADRESS;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    public static String EXTRA_ADDRESS = null;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE=1;
    Set<BluetoothDevice> paired_devices;
String lists[];
boolean conexao = false;
private static final int REQUEST_CONEXAO = 2;

BluetoothDevice myDevice = null;
BluetoothSocket mySocket = null;
Button btnPaired;

ListView devicelist;

ConnectedThread Conectarei;
private static String OMAC_ADRESS = null;


UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button Movimentos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.movimentabotao);
    Button Sobre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sobrebotao);
    Button Manual = (Button) findViewById(R.id.manualbotao);
    btnPaired = (Button) findViewById(R.id.conexao);
    devicelist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if(myBluetooth == null)
    {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Não Disponínel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        finish();
    }
    else if(!myBluetooth.isEnabled())
    {

        Intent turnBTon = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(turnBTon,1);
    }


    Movimentos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Movimentos.class);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });
    Sobre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sobre.class);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });

    Manual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, manual.class);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });
btnPaired.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(conexao){
                //desconectar
                try{
                    mySocket.close();
                    conexao = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Conexão finalizada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    btnPaired.setText("Conectar");

                }catch(IOException erro){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocorreu um erro " + erro, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }else{
                //conectar
                Intent abreLista = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListaDispositivos.class);
                startActivityForResult(abreLista, REQUEST_CONEXAO);
            }

        }
    });

}
public void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent data){

    switch (requestcode){
        case REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultcode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Ativado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Não Ativado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_CONEXAO:
            if(resultcode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                EXTRA_ADDRESS = data.getExtras().getString(MAC_ADRESS);

                myDevice = myBluetooth.getRemoteDevice(EXTRA_ADDRESS);

                try{
                    mySocket = myDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                    mySocket.connect();
                    conexao = true;
                    Conectarei = new ConnectedThread(mySocket);
                    Conectarei.start();
                    btnPaired.setText("Desconectar");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Conectado no Dispositivo " + MAC_ADRESS, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }catch (IOException erro) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ocorreu um erro" + erro, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    conexao = false;
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Falha ao obter MAC ADRESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

    }









}
}
```

ConnectionThread

```
package aluno.fabio.projetofresadora;


import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
    mmSocket = socket;
    OutputStream tmpOut = null;


    try {
        tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) { }

    mmOutStream = tmpOut;
}




public void write(String enviadados) {
    byte[] msgbuffer = enviadados.getBytes();
    try {
        mmOutStream.write(msgbuffer);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
}
}
```

ListaDispositivos

```
    package aluno.fabio.projetofresadora;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Set;


public class ListaDispositivos extends ListActivity {

    private BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter = null;

    static String MAC_ADRESS = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter<String> ArrayBluetooth = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if (pairedDevices.size()>0)
    {
        for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
        {
            String nomebt = bt.getName();
            String macadressdev = bt.getAddress();
            ArrayBluetooth.add(nomebt + "\n" + macadressdev);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sem Dispositivos Pareados", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    setListAdapter(ArrayBluetooth);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    String infoall = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
    String onlymac = infoall.substring(infoall.length() - 17);
    Intent rt = new Intent();
    rt.putExtra(MAC_ADRESS, onlymac);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, rt);
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: [O que é a NullPointerException e quais são suas principais causas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63617)

Comment: Ou o `data` está nulo, ou o `data.getExtras()` retorna nulo.
Muito provavelmente você está esquecendo de mandar a Intent.