# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Estou com problema na linha 141, aonde diz que a string está nula e me aponta o erro nesta linha 
`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());`

Porém não estou conseguindo resolver, abaixo o código junto com o `logcat`:

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());

    String lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results"))
                  .getJSONObject(0)
                  .getJSONObject("geometria")
                  .getJSONObject("localizacao")
                  .get("lat").toString();

    String lng = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results"))
                  .getJSONObject(0)
                  .getJSONObject("geometria")
                  .getJSONObject("localizacao")
                  .get("lng").toString();

    LatLng localizacaoPedido = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat),Double.parseDouble(lng));

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.box);
    bitmap = Comum.scaleBitmap(bitmap, 70, 70);

    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
                .title("Pedido de "+Comum.pedidoAtual.getTelefone())
                .position(localizacaoPedido);
    mMap.addMarker(marker);
```

ERROR:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.daniel.androidpadariaserver.RastreamentoPedido$1.onResponse(RastreamentoPedido.java:141)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: [**O que é a NullPointerException e quais são suas principais causas?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63617/)

Comment: Na hora de fazer a exceção ele fala que response.body().toString() é nula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa verificar se existe uma instância de objeto no seu elemento `response.body()`, uma vez que você faz a invocação de um método, no caso o `toString()`, que não é acessado de forma estática.

Uma solução seria incluir uma validação mínima aí no seu trecho, como no exemplo a seguir:

```
try {
    if(response.body() == null) {
        //Faz o tratamento para quando não existir o elemento body
    } else {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());

        String lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results"))
              .getJSONObject(0)
              .getJSONObject("geometria")
              .getJSONObject("localizacao")
              .get("lat").toString();

        String lng = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results"))
              .getJSONObject(0)
              .getJSONObject("geometria")
              .getJSONObject("localizacao")
              .get("lng").toString();

        LatLng localizacaoPedido = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat),Double.parseDouble(lng));

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.box);
        bitmap = Comum.scaleBitmap(bitmap, 70, 70);

        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
            .title("Pedido de "+Comum.pedidoAtual.getTelefone())
            .position(localizacaoPedido);
        mMap.addMarker(marker);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Apresentou o seguinte erro meu amigo:                                                    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isNull(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z in class Ljava/util/Objects; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.Objects' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)

Comment: Problema de conflito com sua árvore de dependências. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Deu certo meu amigo, o erro sumiu e rodou o projeto, obrigado, se tiver como te reputar algo do tipo me avise, é a primeira vez que solicito ajuda aqui, vlwzao!!

Comment: Basta aceitar a pergunta como a solução do seu problema.