# Erro : java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method trim()

Tags: java, api, rest, restful

Já tentei usar Port e o baseUri e não roda o resto, sempre falha.

Erro completo:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method trim() on null object at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:47) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray

Código do projeto:

```
package br.com.academia.poo;

import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AcademiapooApplicationTests {

    public AcademiapooApplicationTests() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "localhost:8080/" ;
    }

    @Test
    /* Chama o serviço pelo metodo POST */
    public void testCriaUsuario() {
        String myJson = "{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\": \"vanessa\"}";

        given()
            .contentType("application/json")
            .body(myJson)
        .when()
            .post("/clientes")
        .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .body("message",containsString("usuário criado com sucesso"));
    }

    /*
     * @Test public void testPegarCliente() {
     * 
     * given() .when() .get("/clientes/1") .then() .statusCode(200) .body("id",
     * is(1)) .body("username", equalTo("vanessa")) .assertThat()
     * .body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("clienteTest.json")); }
     */
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [O que é a NullPointerException e quais são suas principais causas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63617/o-que-%c3%a9-a-nullpointerexception-e-quais-s%c3%a3o-suas-principais-causas)

Answer (score -1):

O erro que está tendo diz que você está chamando o método TRIM em através de uma string que não foi inicializada com nenhum valor válido, provavelmente um NULO, procure o seu erro ali pelo arquivo PogoMetaClassSite no método call próximo a linha 47.