# Null Pointer Exception?

Tags: java, array

No trecho de código abaixo, é suposto comparar o valor dos items do array `linhas` com a `String` inserida pelo utilizador `p`. Está funcionando, mas dá sempre o erro:

> Stack trace - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at MainSwitch.main(MainSwitch.java:229)

O código:

```java
String guardar;
String lista[] = new String [tamMax];

System.out.println("Insira a palavra que pretende pesquisar:");
p = reader.next();

for(int i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++)
{
    guardar = linhas[i];
    lista = guardar.split(" ");  //linha do erro
    for(int k = 0; k < lista.length; k++)
    {
        if(lista[k].equals(p))
        {
            System.out.println("Linha " + i + ": " + linhas[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque o stacktrace e aponte com um comentário no código a linha do problema.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at MainSwitch.main(MainSwitch.java:229)

O erro é na linha -  lista = guardar.split(" ");

Comment: Sempre bom conferir isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63617/64969; leia todas as respostas. O problema está que seu vetor `linhas` foi inicializado mas não povoado, portanto para algum índice `i` temos que `lista[i] == null`

Comment: Entendi.. E qual a melhor maneira de resolver isso?

Comment: A propósito, se quiser usar comentários `//`, deixe o código a esquerda, se não o código se torna parte do comentário

Comment: Feito, erro meu rsrs

Comment: Depois desta linha `guardar = linhas[i];` tenta colocar `if( guardar == null ) continue;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse erro `java.lang.NullPointerException` indica que você esta tentando utilizar algo que esta **nulo**.

Que no seu caso, pelo que foi postado, indica que algum índice de `linhas` está `null`.

No código postado não mostra a declaração ou como ela esta sendo preenchida.

Entretanto você pode solucionar parte do problema colocando uma checagem antes de utilizar o item, como por exemplo `if( linhas[i] == null ) continue;`

O `continue` volta ao `for` acima mais próximo e faz ele continuar com o próximo índice `i`

```
guardar = linhas[i];
if( guardar == null ) continue;
lista = guardar.split(" ");
```

Agora é bom você checar em seu código como essa `array` esta sendo preenchida.

Comment: O problema está no método que está inserindo strings no array, está saltando a primeira linha do mesmo. Muito obrigado pela explicação