# Problema com java.lang.NullPointerException android.graphics.Bitmap.compress

Tags: java, kotlin, bitmap

Olá estou tendo esse erro em meu código alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver isso?

grato desde já.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
        at map.app.fragments.ReportFragment.putImgToBytearray(ReportFragment.kt:177)
```

Linha do erro

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream)
```

código

```
private fun putImgToBytearray(): ByteArray {
    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val drawable = this.imgThumb!!.drawable as BitmapDrawable
    val bitmap = drawable.bitmap
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream)
    return stream.toByteArray()
}
```

código onActivityResult

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


        try {

            //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
            val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, this.imageUri) as Bitmap?
            this.imgThumb!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            this.pictureTaken = true
        } catch (e:IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error loading image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    }
}
```

método para abrir a galeria e pegar uma imagem,sim é uma adaptação

```
fun openCamera() {
    try {
        val imageFile = createImageFile()
        val callCameraIntent =  Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        if(callCameraIntent.resolveActivity(activity.packageManager) != null) {
            val authorities = activity.packageName + ".fileprovider"
            this.imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, authorities, imageFile)
            callCameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
            startActivityForResult(callCameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE)
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Could not create file!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é a NullPointerException e quais são suas principais causas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63617/o-que-%c3%a9-a-nullpointerexception-e-quais-s%c3%a3o-suas-principais-causas)

Comment: Ola @Marc, seu problema parece ser esta linha `val bitmap = drawable.bitmap`, aparentemente isso `drawable.bitmap` esta retornando `null` então quando você faz essa chamada `bitmap.compress(...)` a variável `bitmap` esta **nula** por isso o erro. Como eu ainda não me aventurei com o [tag:kotlin] não posso te ajudar muito mais que isso =P, verifique se o conteúdo da variável `drawable` possui a propriedade `bitmap` =D