# Estou iniciando em java e estou tendo o erro java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jdbc

ERRO:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.drogaria.dao.FabricanteDAO.excluir(FabricanteDAO.java:33)
    at br.com.drogaria.dao.FabricanteDAO.main(FabricanteDAO.java:64)
```

Embora apareça esse erro ele esta excluindo os dados no BD.  Estou usando a ide eclipse

CÓDIGO:

```
package br.com.drogaria.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import br.com.drogaria.domanin.Fabricante;
import br.com.drogaria.factory.ConexaoFactory;

public class FabricanteDAO {
    public void salvar(Fabricante f) throws SQLException {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("INSERT INTO fabricante ");
        sql.append("(descricao) ");
        sql.append("VALUES (?)");

        Connection conexao = ConexaoFactory.conectar();

        PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        comando.setString(1, f.getDescrição());

        comando.executeUpdate();
    }

    public void excluir(Fabricante f) throws SQLException {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("DELETE FROM fabricante ");
        sql.append("WHERE codigo = ? ");

        Connection conexao = ConexaoFactory.conectar();

        PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        comando.setLong(1, f.getCodigo());

        comando.executeUpdate();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
         * Fabricante f1 = new Fabricante(); f1.setDescrição("DESCRICAO 1");
         * 
         * Fabricante f2 = new Fabricante(); f2.setDescrição("DESCRICAO 2");
         * 
         * FabricanteDAO fdao = new FabricanteDAO();
         * 
         * try { fdao.salvar(f1); fdao.salvar(f2);
         * System.out.println("Os fabricantes foram salvos com sucesso"); } catch
         * (SQLException e) { System.out.println("Erro ao salvar um dos fabricantes");
         * e.printStackTrace(); }
         */

        Fabricante f1 = new Fabricante();
        f1.setCodigo(1L);

        Fabricante f2 = new Fabricante();
        f1.setCodigo(5L);

        FabricanteDAO fdao = new FabricanteDAO();

        try {
            fdao.excluir(f1);
            fdao.excluir(f2);
            System.out.println("Os fabricantes foram removidos com sucesso!");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Ocorreu um erro ao cadastrar um dos fabricantes!");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é a NullPointerException e quais são suas principais causas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63617/o-que-%c3%a9-a-nullpointerexception-e-quais-s%c3%a3o-suas-principais-causas)

Comment: Ola @initJavaWeb, Bem vindo ao SOpt, vale apena você adicionar um comentário ao lado das linhas **33** e **64** indicadas no erro informado, isso vai ajudar a comunidade a identificar o erro, para isso clique em [Edit] abaixo de sua pergunta -- também vale apena você dar uma olhada no nosso [Tour] =D

Comment: Leia isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> at br.com.drogaria.dao.FabricanteDAO.excluir(FabricanteDAO.java:33)
> ```

Essa linha é a seguinte:

```
    comando.setLong(1, f.getCodigo());
```

Sabemos que `comando` não é `null` e que `f` também não é `null`. Logo, o suspeito é que o resultado de `f.getCodigo()` seja `null`.

De acordo com o [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setLong(int,long)), o segundo parâmetro é do tipo `long`. Assim sendo, se você passar `null` no lugar deste parâmetro, o resultado será um `NullPointerException` de *autounboxing*. Veja mais sobre isso no terceiro caso [dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63736/132).

Considerando que você chamou o método `setCodigo(Long)` no seu objeto `Fabricante`, mas mesmo assim o método `getCodigo()` retornou `null`, então a origem do seu `NullPointerException` não está em sua classe `FabricanteDAO`, e sim em sua classe `Fabricante`.

Apesar disso, a sua classe `FabricanteDAO` tem ainda assim um monte de problemas. Recomendo fortemente que você utilize o *try-with-resources*. Veja [nessa outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/132) o porquê de fazer isso e como fazer.

Ah, finalmente isso daqui:

```
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("INSERT INTO fabricante ");
    sql.append("(descricao) ");
    sql.append("VALUES (?)");
```

É algo desnecessário. Você está montando e remontando sempre a mesma SQL pedaço por pedaço todas as vezes que o método `salvar` executa. O melhor seria fazer assim:

```
private static final String INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO fabricante (descricao) VALUES (?)";
```

Pois dessa forma, você constrói a SQL apenas um única vez quando a classe é inicializada e o custo de construí-la é praticamente zero, uma vez que ela já vai estar disponibilizada pronta e inteira dentro do bytecode. O mesmo pode ser dito da sua SQL do método `excluir`.