# Como resolver o erro de Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException no meu programa?

Tags: java

```
public class ClassMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CPessoa[] Pessoas = new CPessoa[10];

        int cont=0, j=0;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            Pessoas[i] = new CPessoa(Pessoas[j].nome, cont);
        }
        cont++;

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            Pessoas[i] = new CPessoa(Pessoas[j].nome, cont);
        }

    }
}







import java.util.Random;

public class CPessoa {

    String nome;
    String[] amigos = new String[10];
    int contamigo = 0;

    public CPessoa(String nomeamigo, int cont) {
        if(cont==0) {
        GeraNome();
        }else
        if(cont!=0) {
        AddAmigo(nomeamigo);
        MostrarAmigos();
        }
    }

    public void AddAmigo(String nomeamigo) {
        amigos[contamigo] = nomeamigo;
        contamigo++;
    }

    public void MostrarAmigos(){
        System.out.printf("Amigos de %s:\n", nome);
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%s\n", amigos[i]);
        }
        }


    public void GeraNome(){
        String[] consoante = new String[] {"b","c","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","x","y","z"};
        String[] vogal = new String[] {"a","e","i","o","u"};
        String[] consoanteM = new String[] {"B","C","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","M","N","P","Q","R","S","T","V","W","X","Y","Z"};

        for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
            int gerarcns = new Random().nextInt(21);
            int gerarvg = new Random().nextInt(5);

            if(i==0) {
                this.nome+=consoanteM[gerarcns];
            }else {
                if(i%2==1) {
                    this.nome+=vogal[gerarvg];
                }else {
                    this.nome+=consoante[gerarcns];
                }           
            }
            gerarcns=0;
            gerarvg=0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Não faça uma pergunta apenas com código. Explique a sua dúvida o mais detalhado possivel. Null pointer exception significa que você está a utilizar um objeto que está a nulo, na linha que é indicada no *Stack trace*

Comment: o erro é porque antes de usar `Pessoas[j].nome` você não inicializa a `Pessoas[j]`.. mas assim como @Isac falou, a pergunta está mal formulada.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é a NullPointerException e quais são suas principais causas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63617/o-que-%c3%a9-a-nullpointerexception-e-quais-s%c3%a3o-suas-principais-causas)

Answer (score 0):

Cara, vc criou o array de CPessoa (Pessoas) e não adicionou nenhuma pessoa, quando vc tenta acessar uma pessoa atraves do código `Pessoas[j].nome`  , será lancado esse erro. E ainda tem um problema, vc tá adicionando itens no array usando os proprios elementos do array. Algo de errado não está certo.