# Spring data Jpa lanca erro de @Autowired e erro de ponteiro nulo

Tags: java, string, jpa

Estou usando Spring Tool Suite para fazer uma aplicação, porém, quando tento lançar os dados do site em html para o banco de dados, o método de serviços relativo á salvar e gerar persistência retorna `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Ora, os dados que recebo são coerentes, ou seja, vai do html pro java sem problemas, mas dá esse erro quando invoco essa parte, incluindo a aplicação trava se eu coloco o método de salvar fora de try-catch. Se adiciono `@Autowired` em cima do parâmetro de serviços, aí que dá erro mesmo, e trava:

> description:
>
> Field fazer in com.example.demo.Control.InicialControler required a bean of type 'Services.Servicos' that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>       - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'Services.Servicos' in your configuration.

O que pode ser?

```
@Entity
public class Ficha implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) //@Column(name = "id", unique = true)
public long id;

private String nome;

private String email;

private String sugestao;


public Ficha() {

}

public Ficha( @NotNull String nome, @NotNull String email, @NotNull String sugestao) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.email = email;
    this.sugestao = sugestao;
}


/*GETTERS E SETTERS*/
}
```

Controle:

```
@RestController
public class InicialControler {

//@Autowired
private Servicos fazer ;

@RequestMapping("/sugestoes")
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView mostrarSugestao(Ficha fichar){


    ModelAndView mostrar = new ModelAndView();
    mostrar.setViewName("sugestao");
    mostrar.addObject("fichar", fichar);
    Ficha fichando = new Ficha(fichar.getNome(), fichar.getEmail(), fichar.getSugestao());


    try {
        fazer.cadastrar(fichando);
//fazer.SaveFlush(fichando);
        System.out.println("be save" );
    }catch(Exception e) {
System.out.println( "erro ==> "  + e.getLocalizedMessage() + " " + e + " " +fichando.toString());
    }

    return mostrar;
}
}
```

Servico:

```
@Service
public class Servicos implements GenericosServicos<Ficha, Long>   {

@Autowired
RepositorioDados repositar;

@Override
public Optional<Ficha> buscarPorId(Long id) {
    return repositar.findById(id);
}

@Override
public Ficha cadastrar(Ficha t) {

     return repositar.save(t);  
}

public void Save(Ficha t) {
    repositar.save(t);
}

@Override
public Ficha alterar(Long k, Ficha t) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<Ficha> ListarTodos() {
    return repositar.findAll();
}

@Override
public void deletar(Long k) {
    repositar.deleteById(k);
}


}
```

Interface:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface RepositorioDados extends JpaRepository<Ficha, Long> {

public Ficha save(Ficha user);

}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.model"})//nome do pacote aonde está a entidade
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"DAO"})/nome do pacote aonde está o repositorio
public class PrimeSrpingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PrimeSrpingApplication.class, args);
    }

}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>


<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>PrimeSrping</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver inicialmente seu NullPointerException, você precisa injetar uma referência de Servicos usando a anotação [@Autowired](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) do Spring.

```
@Autowired
private Servicos fazer;
```

Para entender o que é NullPointerException, [clique aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63617/o-que-%C3%A9-a-nullpointerexception-e-quais-s%C3%A3o-suas-principais-causas)

Comment: Não, se eu coloco @Autowired emcima da instancia de servicos, dá esse erro:Description:

Field fazer in com.example.demo.Control.InicialControler required a bean of type 'Services.Servicos' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'Services.Servicos' in your configuration.  
                                                                   Queria saber como fazer esse negócio direito, até instanciei Servicos,  mas não deu certo

Comment: @Tim perfeito, o erro que você citou agora significa que o Spring não conseguiu identificar uma implementação valida da interface Servicos (ainda não é o caso de remover a anotação do @Autowired). Você está usando o que ? Spring Framework ou Spring Boot ? Tem como você editar a pergunta novamente e colocar a sua configuração do respectivo Spring?

Comment: Sim, estou usando Spring Tool Suite e suas configurações. Ora, eu ganho um erro de ponteiro nulo ao usar isso aí, exceto se coloco @Autowired  emcima do objeto servicos, aí dá erro e trava.

Comment: Spring Tool Suite é uma extensão do Eclipse IDE para trabalhar com o framework Spring. Lendo seus fontes agora, notei que você está usando a implementação do Spring Boot. Na sua classe PrimeSpringApplication.java, anote ela com a anotação @ComponentScan("PACOTE-DO-SEUS-SERVICOS-AQUI"), a principio é esta anotação que falta para o Spring reconhecer as implementações dos seus serviços, não esqueça de manter o @Autowired que pedi para você colocar no comentário anterior.

Comment: Não tem erro no compilador, porém quando vou no navegador abrir a tela dá erro de pagina em branco: 
 Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.  There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available. Mas funciona normal, se tiro o Autowired de cima do objeto de servicos, e o ComponentScan da classe PrimeSpringApplication.